# RHEL 7 doesn't mount drive from /etc/fstab on boot?

Tags: rhel7

I have a RHEL 7 server with this line in `/etc/fstab`:

```
\\10.0.0.1\backup /mnt/backup cifs user,uid=500,rw,suid,username=admin,password=password 0 0
```

It is exact same line that I am using on other CentOS 6 and RHEL 6 servers, but on this single RHEL 7 box it seems I need to connect and run `mount -a` after every reboot?

Is some way to solve this automatically?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `_netdev` and `auto` mount options to ensure that the mount happens at boot and won't be attempted before network is up and running.

[**`man mount`**](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount)

> **`_netdev`**
>
> ```
> The filesystem resides on a device that requires network access (used to prevent the
> system from attempting to mount these filesystems until the network has been enabled 
> on the system).  
>   ....
> ```
>
> **`auto`**
>
> ```
> Can be mounted with the -a option.
> ```